# Laravel 5 pass select data to controller

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using a plugin called select2.  In one of my views, I have a button which simply opens a modal.  Inside this modal, I have a select input (not within a form).  I also have a button which currently links to a route e.g.

```
{!! link_to_route('projects.doc.emailPdf', 'Email PDF', array($project->id, $project->doc->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-info email-sbt')) !!}
```

Now really, I need to pass the selected data to this route as well.  However, I think the only way to get the selected data is via JQuery

```
$('.email-sbt').on("click", function(){
    alert($('.email-select').select2('data'));
});
```

So how can I get the data from my select to the route my button calls?

Thanks

Comment: Kate, what is `link_to_route`? a custom function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question at all. You can not edit the route's parameters after your view has been rendered, because it has been converted to a string. However, you can make some changes at your html markup. Let's say you have this view:

```
 <!-- An anchor to email a pdf (id not specified) -->
<a href="#" id="btn-email" data-url="/email/pdf/">Email PDF</a>

<!-- Select pdf id number -->
<select class="email-sbt">
    ....
</select>
```

So, based in your selection via Select2 element, you can edit this anchor with jquery as you did with extra lines:

```
$('.email-sbt').on("click", function(){
    var id = $('.email-select').select2('data');

    // creates an url like /email/pdf/3
    var url =  $('#btn-email').data('url') + id;

    // update the button's url
    $('#btn-email').attr('href', url);
});
```